# Lagrange Vs Sinc interpolation

Tags: discrete-signals, digital-communications, sampling, interpolation, reconstruction

I was wondering what is the practical difference between Lagrange Interpolation using Farrow Structure and Sinc Interpolation? Both require pre-computation of time offset coefficients using a lookup table.

Is the length of filter required for a certain degree of accuracy less for one over the other? How do they compare?

Comment: it turns out that, since both Lagrange and **windowed** sinc have the interpolated function go directly through the original points, you can actually come up with an effective impulse response for Lagrange that looks like a sinc.  you can divide that Lagrange impulse response by a sinc, deal with the 0/0 singularities and come up with an effective window.  Lagrange **is** an example of windowed sinc.

Comment: @PeterK. *Kootsookos and Williams (1995) have proved that the Lagrange interpolation coefficients can also be obtained by windowing the shifted and sampled sinc function with a scaled binomial window...* May be you have samething to say...

Comment: I understand that in the limit the Lagrange interpolation approaches ideal sinc but that doesn't address the question of windowed sinc vs windowed lagrange.